# Creating a custom javascript keyboard

Tags: javascript, keyboard

Im quite new to javascript but Im having to build a keyboard I have seen some of the other posts and they helped me find this online keyboard.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-keyboard-with-css-and-jquery/

I have taken this and altered it so it works for me better. The issue im having is the fact when I click on a button im getting no input on the on screen display.

I have attached my code here http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=7cD8eunmBG

Comment: Once I uncomment the Javascript and set it to JQuery 1.10.1, it works fine for me.  I'm in Chrome btw.

Comment: I cant use JQuery I have to use javascript

Comment: The code requires jQuery